# For how long can a single-engine turboprop safely run the engine at idle?

Tags: engine, turboprop

Can a single engine turboprop (such as a Piper Meridian or TBM) allow idling long enough to drop off a passenger or package without shutting down the engine? If so, would the prop be feathered but still spinning? Would idling with the prop not spinning (if possible) hurt the engine?

Comment: The question one should be asking is whether they want to incur the risk of someone running into the prop on a package or passenger drop off.  The issue is really a best practices issue.  However, I seem to remember the factory commenting on extended idle times for the PT6-67A but I lack any documentation on that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not stressful at all for a turbine engine to run at idle, you could run it until the fuel runs out. The prop is not feathered (in line with the air stream, pitch 90°) but will be at ground fine, in line with the direction of blade turn, pitch angle 0°.

There is usually no way to disconnect a propeller from a single spool turbine engine: if the engine runs, the propeller turns.

Comment: With the prop turning relatively slowly, you can always feather it, with the blades in line with the air stream, but not at a pitch of 90º, but somewhat less... In that way, drag will be minimized...